# Auditing logging on only one SharePoint 2007 Document Library or List

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, moss2007-security

I would like to know if it is possible to get audit logs on only one document library or list. I wouldn't like to do it at site collection or server farm level.

Also, is it possible in the audit logs to get information for the case of editing, what the original information was before editing and the new information?

Thanks in advance,

Matrich

Answer (score 1):

1. In List Settings (or Library Settings) choose Information Management Policy settings.
2. Choose the "Define a policy..." radio button and choose OK.
3. Check the "Enable auditing" check box and that will show the auditable events that you can enable.  Choose the ones that you want to track and click OK.

As for keeping track of what changed...I believe you will be better served by versioning enabled.